# Why does my Angular service request not reach Java servlet?

Tags: java, angular, servlets, service

guys:

I am new to Angular. Our team is rewriting the front end with Angular 16.1.8, and keep Java (open JDK 1.8) as back end programming language. I need to implement a log class in Angular so we can save the GUI log information to backend file. We plan to send a log service call from GUI and use a Java servlet to accept request and to write to a log file with existing Java log4j. However, I cannot make the log service call to reach the servlet; no statement is ever executed in the servlet at all in debugging mode. On the other side, everything goes fine before my code makes the service call. There are also other service calls similarly, other servlets do get the requests. Can anyone give me a hint?

I attach the Angular code as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { WebServiceClient } from './web.service.client';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LogService {

    constructor(private departureService : WebServiceClient) { }

    public logToServer(severity : string, message : string) {
    // We are using POST instead of GET for security reasons. GET is flagged by 
    // Software Security testing tools like WebInspect
        return this.departureService.post(
          "http://localhost:8080/departures"
          , '/application-log'
          , {
             "applicationName" :  "Departure-ui",
             "dateTime" : new Date(),
             "severity" : severity,
              "message" : message
         }
         , "json");
    }

  }
```

I would attach the Java code as follows:

```
package gov.faa.infra.ifp.web.portlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import gov.faa.infra.ifp.bo.IfpAccessBo.ModeType;
import gov.faa.infra.ifp.domain.ResponseMessage.Importance;
import gov.faa.infra.ifp.util.IfpSession;
import gov.faa.infra.ifp.util.JsonUtils;

@WebServlet("/application-log")
public class LogServlet extends BaseServiceServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger logger = null;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
        throw new ServletException("GET method is not supported");
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int transactionHashCode = -1;
        String parameter = null;
        Boolean serviceIsValid = null;
        int status = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK;
        String statusMessage = null;

        Log logInput = null;
        String severity = null;
        String logMessage = null;

        try {
            transactionHashCode = 
                    IfpSession.getSession().beginReadOnlyTransaction();
            
            if(this.verifyAccess(ModeType.QueryFlightProcedure, request)) {
                logInput = JsonUtils.hydrateObject(
                            (parameter = this.readInputAsString(request))
                            , Log.class);

                
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(logInput.getMessage())) {
                    logMessage = "";
                    
                    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(logInput.getDateTime()))
                        logMessage = logMessage + logInput.getDateTime();
                    
                    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(logInput.getApplicationName()))
                        logMessage = logMessage + logInput.getApplicationName();                
                    
                    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(logInput.getSeverity()))
                        logMessage = logMessage + logInput.getSeverity();
                    
                    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(logInput.getMessage()))
                        logMessage = logMessage + logInput.getMessage();
                    
                    severity = logInput.getSeverity();
                    
                    switch (severity) {
                        case "success": 
                            logger.trace(logMessage);
                            break;
                        case "info": 
                            logger.info(logMessage);
                            break;
                        case "warning": 
                            logger.warn(logMessage);
                            break;
                        case "error": 
                            logger.error(logMessage);
                            break;
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    IfpSession.getSession().addMessage(Importance.Failure, "empty log message", null);
                    status = HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST;
                }
                
            }
            else
                status = HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED;       
                IfpSession.getSession().addMessage(Importance.Failure, "unauthorized access", null);
            
        }
        catch(Exception exception) {
            this.ifpSessionResponseWithExceptionAndRollback(
                    response, null, transactionHashCode
                    , "unable to write log" 
                            + (statusMessage == null 
                                    ? "" : " while " + statusMessage)
                    , exception
                    , new Object[] { 
                            serviceIsValid, parameter 
                    });
        }
        finally {
            IfpSession.getSession().rollbackTransaction(transactionHashCode);
            this.logTiming("completed LogServlet.doPost", start);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should be calling this metod something like `logService.logToServer('warning', 'message').subscribe()`, because angular http service returns observables. Observables are lazy and won't even be called without implicit or explicit calls of `.subscribe()`

Comment: the WebServiceClient what does it return? Also it has 4 parameters, they seem a bit weird, can you reveal how the post method looks like from that service. Just to provide a clearer understanding how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check if not a CORS policy prohibits calling your backend. It might be a good idea to use a proxy while developing. Can you see some error message in your console?